# How to create a Joda DateTime from a String

Tags: android, datetime

I have a String "26/09/2012 07:30:00" is it possible to create a new DateTime based on this String? Eventually i just want the time eg 7:30. I am going to format the DateTime by using DateFormatter eg

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("k,m");
```

My question is how to construct a DT from the orginal String, i can format it once it's a DT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an appropriate [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the input format, and then call [`DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseLocalDateTime%28java.lang.String%29). (`LocalDateTime` is more appropriate than `DateTime` here, as your input data doesn't have a time zone or UTC offset indicator. You can convert to `DateTime` if you *really* need to, but it sound like you don't.)

Comment: Hi, I've looked at the API for joda but I can't seem to work out how the API is to be used. Sorry if it's obvious. Could you elaborate a little? Do i need a builder to start with eg DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().formatter....;

Comment: @turtleboy: You've already *got* code which creates a `DateTimeFormat` - it's in your question! You just need one with your *input* pattern...

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();   

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());        
Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// Now we display formattedDate value in TextView
TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+formattedDate);
txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
txtView.setTextSize(20);
setContentView(txtView);
```